# Is it possible in excel pivot table to apply the report filter only to one column with vba

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have the following dataset:

[image]

Employees from different team are assigned to some tasks and `completion rate` column shows how much of the assigned task is completed. I want to know the percentage of people in each team who have completed more than half of their task.

In the below image the first pivot table is filtered for items with `completion rate >50%`. The highlighted data in yellow show the first table data divided by the second table data. I want to get these highlighted data.

[image]

I can get this solution if I add another column to my initial dataset and create a pivot table.

However I am looking for a nicer solution where I won't need an extra column in my initial dataset. I would like to know maybe it is possible to combine these 2 pivot tables into one and then apply the division.

Comment: Why don't you want to enhance the original dataset? Adding two more columns would make it very simple to get your solution with one pivot table that uses a calculated field.

Comment: I did, I have this solution and I can share it, but when you look at  the formulas in the dataset and in the pivot table, it is not obvious for the users of the file what you want to do. Besides, I am making this report for 5 different percentage ranges from 0 to 100  and I need to add 10  more columns. So I thought maybe there is a nicer solution.

Comment: Sorry, good luck. If you need 5 ranges, then 6 columns would solve it. One column is always "1", and other is a 1/0 flag for the desired completion rate. Then calculated formula is [your completion rate OneZero column / your column with 1]. But I may not fully understand the output, so maybe there's more to it.

Comment: This is something that can be done without VBA in PowerPivot. Create a measure that filters based on the pivot table selections, and another measure that ignores the filters. You can even create a measure for the completion rate.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the area of each pivot table, calculate the value for this area, and get the result.

### PivotTable Rowrange

The RowRange of the pivot table is as follows.

[image]

### PivotTable DataBodyRange

[image]

### Code

```
Sub test()
    Dim pv(1 To 2) As PivotTable
    Dim vRng(1 To 2) As Range
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Set pv(1) = Ws.PivotTables(1) 'Check and set the index number of your pivot table.
    Set pv(2) = Ws.PivotTables(2) 'Check and set the index number of your pivot table.
    
    
    Set rngDB = pv(1).RowRange
    vDB = pv(1).RowRange
    'rngDB.Select
    For i = 1 To 2
        Set vRng(i) = pv(i).DataBodyRange
        'vRng(i).Select
        'Stop
    Next i
    
    r = vRng(1).Rows.Count
    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To r - 1
        vR(i, 1) = vDB(i + 1, 1)
        vR(i, 2) = vRng(2).Cells(i) / vRng(1).Cells(i)
    Next i
    Range("o2").Resize(r, 2) = vR
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. This works, too. I just wondered if it is possible to do it in one pivot table.

Comment: @Ani, It would be more convenient to use sql based on adodb.